# What "tool" to extrapolate traffic data on graph used for routing (Open Street Maps).

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, optimization, directed-graphs, extrapolation

**Background (non-math)**:
I'm planning to use Open Street Maps data to find the fastest route by car between points. Data is a **directed graph** where vertices represent locations, and edges are routes. Routes have weights that refer to: length and travel speed. There are numerous route finding algorithms, and I don't want to bother anyone with such obvious questions. **The actual problem refers to the fact that I want to use traffic historical data. Traffic data is represented by an additional edge weights, that are used to modify travel speed per edge. Unfortunately the traffic data is available only for a subset of roads (edges). I need to find a "tool" to extrapolate the traffic data to edges that lack it. Without applying extrapolated traffic data the algorithms would automatically choose roads where the traffic data is missing.**

**Question**: I don't have traffic data for all graph edges representing roads (only for a subset), and the missing data has to be extrapolated. What mathematical tools can I use to extrapolate/ fill/ guess the missing traffic data given following assumptions:

**Assumptions**:

- Ideal arbitrage is performed by drivers. Taking a route without (or partially without) traffic data shouldn't give an advantage.
- The solution can be either: geo-agnostic (refer only on nodes and edge weights) or take into account spatial data ie. physical proximity (or direction!) of graph edges.
  Any heuristic can take advantage of the fact that the routing happens for morning or evening rush hours. The traffic significantly differs depending on the direction.
  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think one easy method would be to forbid passing where there are no drives. If the road had no drivers, maybe there is a reason (monsters, potholes etc).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. No traffic data doesn't mean no drivers, the reason for missing data is typically low road "rank". I cannot forbid passing, as those are sometimes best/ only roads to exit a neighbourhood. They simply shouldn't be treated as preferred roads because of missing traffic data.

Comment: Got it. I don't think there is a systematic method. You need some domain knowledge to try and guess what the typical traffic value is. For example, suppose that it is a linear combination of neighboring routes with unknown weights and then guess the weights by considering routes where you know the values and tune the weights to fit as best as possible (a regression or a machine learning approach).

Comment: Can you give a hint what regression model or ML methods to investigate? I created a simple illustration of what is considered as error that I'm trying to minimise: [link](https://ibb.co/PwjbBnB) . The number of edges is approx 30.000.

Comment: As I said, inventing heuristics is domain specific. Here are two options: 1) "safe": for every unknown speed, replace it with half the slowest speed of the neighboring links. 2) interpolation: replace the unknown value with a weighted average of the neighbors. Determine the weights by a best fit to other links with the same neighbor structure  and known speed values (in your example, a quadrangle with a diagonal through it). Neither of these methods are very good, but at least they are are starting point.